# AWS S3 boto download error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, boto3, zappa

I'm using AWS S3 with the help of the boto3 client in flask. I'm able to upload my files successfully to the s3 bucket. 
[Deployed Appliation](https://k8m00unpc6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) https://k8m00unpc6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev

I've been getting an error `{"message":"Forbidden"}`.
The following code explains the implementation of the download in flask.

```
@app.route('/download/<filename>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def download(filename):
    return send_file('https://s3.amazonaws.com/zappa-jepozm5pw/'+filename+'_'+session['email']+'.doc',as_attachment=True)
```

Also I've given public access to all files.I'm also able to download the provided link when I enter it into a browser. When I implement it in flask, the efforts go in vain. What might be the error?

Comment: Does flask.send_file() actually support URLs?

Comment: I’ve also tried return redirect(url). Still the same error. Have been stuck with it for a few hours ...

Comment: @SaicharanReddy were you able to find a fix ?